# Tapku calender customization

Tags: ios7.1, tapku

I'm using `Tapku` calendar for my iOS app. I have something to do like this.
I'm getting a JSON array of data from the web service. It's something like this:

```
dates":[{"day_id":1,"color_id":1},
{"day_id":2,"color_id":1},
{"day_id":3,"color_id":1},
{"day_id":4,"color_id":1},
{"day_id":5,"color_id":1},
{"day_id":6,"color_id":1},
{"day_id":7,"color_id":1},
{"day_id":8,"color_id":1},
{"day_id":9,"color_id":1},
{"day_id":10,"color_id":1},
{"day_id":11,"color_id":1},
{"day_id":12,"color_id":1},
{"day_id":13,"color_id":1},
{"day_id":14,"color_id":1},
{"day_id":15,"color_id":1},
{"day_id":16,"color_id":1},
{"day_id":17,"color_id":1},
{"day_id":18,"color_id":1},
{"day_id":19,"color_id":2},
{"day_id":20,"color_id":2},
{"day_id":21,"color_id":1},
{"day_id":22,"color_id":1},
{"day_id":23,"color_id":1},
{"day_id":24,"color_id":1},
{"day_id":25,"color_id":1},
{"day_id":26,"color_id":1},
{"day_id":27,"color_id":2},
{"day_id":28,"color_id":1},
{"day_id":29,"color_id":1},
{"day_id":30,"color_id":1},
{"day_id":31,"color_id":1}]}
```

Each day has a particular colour to show on the calender. colour_id 1 -red,2-green and 3-yellow.

I can change the
`- (NSArray*)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView marksFromDate:(NSDate *)startDate toDate:(NSDate *)lastDate`

by giving dates with the colour id. My problem is how can I change the select image in `Tapkucalender`by checking the colour_id coming along with a particular date.

This is what I need to do with my `TapkuCalender`

[image]